# Why do I have to click my submit button twice?

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2

I have quite a huge form for data capture. The main problem is that I'll always have to click on the submit button twice in order for the form to be submitted. The first time I press it, it just refreshes and does nothing. Why is this so? Inside my form, there is plenty of input text.

There are also some dynamic select menus, in which its list of items changes depending on the selected item in a different menu. My suspicion is is that the problem lies here as there are valueChangeListener, onchange="submit()" and immediate="true", which might have some side effects that I don't quite understand. I'm not getting any error messages though. Anyone faced any such problem before?

```
<h:commandButton type="submit" value="Add Job Profile" action="{formBean.commitData}"/>

    public void commitData() {
    QueryRunner run = new QueryRunner(ds);
    String insertSql = "sql command here";

    try {
        int numberOfCommits = run.update(insertSql);
        if (numberOfCommits > 0) {
            JOptionPane jop = new JOptionPane("Inserted " + numberOfCommits +"record");
            JDialog dialog = jop.createDialog("Upload complete");
            dialog.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
            dialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
            dialog.setVisible(true);
        } else {
            JOptionPane jop = new JOptionPane("Upload  failed.  Please try again." );
            JDialog dialog = jop.createDialog("Upload failed");
            dialog.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
            dialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
            dialog.setVisible(true);

        }

    } catch (SQLException sqle) {
        sqle.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I don't even get the upload failed message on first click. On second click, upload succeeds.

EDIT: Yup, it's the dynamic select menus. I'm able to submit on first click if i remove these menus. Still, how do I resolve this?

```
<h:outputLabel value="Family: " />
<h:selectOneMenu id="selectFamily"
                 value = "#{formBean.selectedFamily}"
                 valueChangeListener="#{menuBean.changeFamily}"
                 onchange="submit()"
                 immediate = "true" >
<f:selectItems id="familyNames" value="#{menuBean.familyNames}" />
</h:selectOneMenu>


<h:outputLabel value="Function: " />
<h:selectOneMenu id="selectFunction"
                 value="#{formBean.selectedFunction}"
                 immediate="true" >

<f:selectItems id="functionNames" 
               value="#{menuBean.functions}" />
</h:selectOneMenu>

    // listen for family change and render relevant function
       public void changeFamily(ValueChangeEvent event) {
          FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
          String value = (String) event.getNewValue();
          switchFunctions(value);
          context.renderResponse();
        }
```

Comment: Have you tried setting immediate="true" on the button?

Comment: yup already did so, and that made things even worse. everything is passed as null in my input fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem showing pop ups. After the pop up was shown, clicking the submit button only refreshed the pop up. No data was synchronized with the managed bean. However, when the button was clicked again, then it submitted the data.

I resolved this by changing the code which shows the pop up, from...

```
<a4j:commandButton value="Reserve" disabled="#{login.mayReserve == false}" immediate="true"
        title="To set an available number to the Reserved state."
        oncomplete="#{rich:component('selectCustomer')}.show();" render="selectCustomer" >
    <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{managementController.menuAction}" value="Reserve" />
</a4j:commandButton>
```

To...

```
<a4j:commandButton value="Reserve" disabled="#{login.mayReserve == false}" immediate="true"
        title="To set an available number to the Reserved state." render="selectCustomer" >
    <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{managementController.menuAction}" value="Reserve" />
    <a4j:ajax event="click" oncomplete="#{rich:component('selectCustomer')}.show()" reRender="@all" />
</a4j:commandButton>
```

I'm not sure what the technicalities of this are but maybe it helps someone going forward...

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the `valueChangeListener` got triggered on submit as well. The line `context.renderResponse()` will cause the invoke application phase being completely skipped. The `valueChangeListener` will be triggered when the initial menu value wasn't the same as the submitted value. Verify this.

Anyway, having synchronous dropdown menus like that in combination with validation on other input fields in the same form is really a pita. So to make a long story short, here's just a link: [populate child menus (in JSF)](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2007/10/populate-child-menus.html).

Comment: hi BalusC, your method probably works, but I think its way too much code to perform such a simple task. I found a simpler ajax solution at http://www.coreservlets.com/JSF-Tutorial/jsf2/#Ajax . Tried it and it works. Primefaces also offers another simple ajax solution http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/pprSelect.jsf though I have not tried that one yet.